# Matlab:Sampling Curve into Frames and Plotting

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, sampling, continuous-signals

I have a Output Curve of following characteristics

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fTVl.jpg

Following is the data which represents the output curve cited above

```
0   1228.15406117455    1213.71796132282    1199.44623423626    1185.33715849069    1171.38902630825    1157.60014358826    1143.96882993237    1130.49341866405    1117.17225684288    1104.00370527364    1090.98613851046    1078.11794485629    1065.39752635781    1052.82329879590    1040.39369167202    1028.10714819050    1015.96212523702    1003.95709335331    992.090536708388    980.360953066379    968.766853751044    957.306763607236    945.979220959370    934.782777567031    923.715998577884    912.777462477973    901.965761039541    891.279499266498    880.717295337626    870.277780547640    859.959599246218    849.761408775075    839.681879403208    829.719694260385    819.873549268974    810.142153074209    800.524226972966    791.018504841132    781.623733059661    772.338670439371    763.162088144576    754.092769615612    745.129510490332    736.271118524637    727.516413512102    718.864227202765    710.313403221133    701.862796983477    693.511275614446    685.257717863085    677.101014018280    669.040065823703    661.073786392290    653.201100120311    645.420942601057    637.732260538220    630.134011658968    622.625164626790    615.204698954125    607.871604914830    600.624883456507    593.463546112736    586.386614915240    579.393122306018    572.482111049470    565.652634144552    558.903754736983    552.234546031533    545.644091204419    539.131483315831    532.695825222615    526.336229491134    520.051818310328    513.841723405001    507.705085949342    501.641056480713    495.648794813713    489.727469954538    483.876260015660    478.094352130827    472.380942370417    466.735235657145    461.156445682143    455.643794821435    450.196514052799    444.813842873049    439.495029215736    434.239329369281    429.046007895553    423.914337548901    418.843599195643    413.833081734033    408.882082014698    403.989904761570    399.155862493301    394.379275445192    389.659471491612    384.995786068946    380.387562099043    375.834149913207    371.334907176693    366.889198813755    362.496396933217    358.155880754588    353.867036534721    349.629257495012    345.441943749158    341.304502231452    337.216346625644    333.176897294352    329.185581209025    325.241831880470    321.345089289941    317.494799820775    313.690416190604    309.931397384121    306.217208586402    302.547321116805    298.921212363411    295.338365718043    291.798270511836    288.300421951372    284.844321055367    281.429474591926    278.055395016351    274.721600409499    271.427614416707    268.172966187255    264.957190314395    261.779826775920    258.640420875285    255.538523183269    252.473689480189    249.445480698649    246.453462866826    243.497207052304    240.576289306430    237.690290609210    234.838796814729    232.021398597103    229.237691396949    226.487275368383    223.769755326528    221.084740695544    218.431845457169    215.810688099765    213.220891567874    210.662083212278    208.133894740554    205.635962168130    203.167925769835    200.729430031931    198.320123604641    195.939659255160    193.587693821135    191.263888164634    188.967907126584    186.699419481673    184.458097893730    182.243618871551    180.055662725203    177.893913522768    175.758059047548    173.647790755713    171.562803734401    169.502796660248    167.467471758370    165.456534761766    163.469694871160    161.506664715267    159.567160311482    157.650901026989    155.757609540290    153.887011803139    152.038837002892    150.212817525260    148.408688917462    146.626189851781    144.865062089509    143.125050445289    141.405902751840    139.707369825069    138.029205429564    136.371166244459    134.733011829684    133.114504592569    131.515409754832    129.935495319916    128.374532040696    126.832293387534    125.308555516696    123.803097239110    122.315699989477    120.846147795722    119.394227248782    117.959727472736    116.542440095264    115.142159218437    113.758681389832    112.391805573974    111.041333124092    109.707067754198    108.388815511474    107.086384748976    105.799586098638    104.528232444585    103.272138896747    102.031122764767    100.805003532210    99.5936028310572    98.3967444164976    97.2142541419957    96.0459599346504    94.8916917708293    93.7512816520819    92.6245635813268    91.5113735393103    90.4115494613329    89.3249312142428    88.2513605736907    87.1906812016462    86.1427386241704    85.1073802094438    84.0844551460460    83.0738144214844    82.0753108009696    81.0887988064351    80.1141346957970    79.1511764424544    78.1997837150241    77.2598178573099    76.3311418685023    75.4136203836077    74.5071196541023    73.6115075288110    72.7266534350062    71.8524283597264    70.9887048313103    70.1353569011454    69.2922601256279    68.4592915483322    67.6363296823873    66.8232544930576    66.0199473805265    65.2262911628803    64.4421700592893    63.6674696733859    62.9020769768354    62.1458802930985    61.3987692813833    59.4883213755835    57.6483869118112    55.8755259367794    54.1665202384763    52.5183563982524    50.9282102384589    49.3934325474650    47.9115359739955    46.4801829919653    45.0971748454356    43.7604413910364    42.4680317622626    41.2181057864981    40.0089260915283    38.8388508436906    37.7063270647464    36.6098844790632    35.5481298468222    34.5197417427304    33.5234657431651    32.5581099878283    31.6225410848696    30.7156803310698    29.8365002210865    28.9840212219663    28.1573087911403    27.3554706179645    26.5776540705486    25.8230438311588    25.0908597048888    24.3803545875820    23.6908125801659    23.0215472376397    22.3718999419403    21.7412383888150    21.1289551796556    20.5344665100015    19.9572109471129    19.3966482896451    18.8522585030342    18.3235407247356    17.8100123339373    17.3112080808174    16.8266792708190    16.3559929997865    15.8987314361504    15.4544911466551    15.0228824624129    14.6035288823265    14.1960665111621    13.8001435297733    13.4154196951792    13.0415658683801    12.6782635679663    12.3252045477276    11.9820903966137    11.6486321595240    11.3245499775272    11.0095727462157    10.7034377910043    10.4058905582723    10.1166843213306    9.83557990027752    9.56234539487254    9.29675592962605    9.03859341036164    8.78764629156238    8.54370935386321    8.30658349109817    8.07607550635358    7.85199791651758    7.63416876485290    7.42241144115244    7.21655450906823    7.01643154023247    6.82188095481515    6.63274586818697    6.44887394337809    6.27011724904377    6.09633212266684    5.92737903874406    5.76312248171972    5.60343082344452    5.44817620495165    5.29723442235448    5.15048481668219    5.00781016748056    4.86909659001510    4.73423343592343    4.60311319717196    4.47563141318063    4.35168658098654    4.23118006832444    4.11401602950876    4.00010132400749    3.88934543760435    3.78166040605072    3.67696074111369    3.57516335893142    3.47618751059112    3.37995471484913    3.28638869291620    3.19541530523493    3.10696249017925    3.02096020460939    2.93734036621838    2.85603679760903    2.77698517204319    2.70012296080697    2.62538938213866    2.55272535166765    2.48207343431511    2.41337779760910    2.34658416636844    2.28163977871173    2.21849334334935    2.15709499811800    2.09739626971883    2.03935003462156    1.98291048109845    1.92803307235332    1.87467451071194    1.82279270284141    1.77234672596718    1.72329679505757    1.67560423094658    1.62923142936686    1.58414183086548    1.54029989157635    1.49767105482374    1.45622172353228    1.41591923341968    1.37673182694912    1.33862862801892    1.30157961736815    1.26555560867691    1.23052822534142    1.19646987790401    1.16335374211922    1.13115373763752    1.09984450728875    1.06940139694817    1.03980043596818    1.01101831815952    0.983032383306248   0.955820599199133   0.929361544172696   0.903634390131477   0.878618886051614   0.854295341944170   0.830644613267103   0.807648085773110   0.785287660780989   0.763545740858505   0.742405215905110   0.721849449623219   0.701862266367018   0.682427938358193   0.663531173258183   0.645157102086936   0.627291267478379   0.609919612263140   0.593028468369314   0.576604546032312   0.560634923305132   0.545107035860604   0.530008667077409   0.515327938401923   0.501053299978151   0.487173521538225   0.473677683546191   0.460555168587976   0.447795653000654   0.435389098734315   0.423325745440032   0.411596102777619   0.400190942937019   0.389101293367371   0.378318429707958   0.367833868915394   0.357639362581574   0.347726890437081   0.338088654034864   0.328717070609165   0.319604767104817   0.310744574372160   0.302129521522970   0.293752830442904   0.285607910456123   0.277688353137837   0.269987927270671   0.262500573940842   0.255220401770266   0.248141682280806   0.241258845386994   0.234566475013650   0.228059304834930   0.221732214131435   0.215580223762081   0.209598492247567   0.203782311962319   0.198127105431917   0.192628421733057   0.187281932993220   0.182083430987262   0.177028823828250   0.172114132749923   0.167335488978228   0.162689130689473   0.158171400052687   0.153778740353848   0.149507693199712   0.145354895799043   0.141317078319080   0.137391061315172   0.133573753231541   0.129862147971212   0.126253322533180   0.122744434714959   0.119332720878702   0.116015493779123   0.112790140451515   0.109654120158199   0.106604962391776   0.103640264933625   0.100757691966098   0.0979549722369389  0.0952298972744753  0.0925803196521720  0.0900041513011877  0.0874993618696001  0.0850639771270087  0.0826960774132594  0.0803937961300688  0.0781553182743600  0.0759788790121574  0.0738627622919147  0.0718052994961873  0.0698048681305858  0.0678598905489812  0.0659688327139552  0.0641302029915237  0.0623425509791821  0.0606044663663534  0.0589145778263389  0.0572715519389033  0.0556740921426450  0.0541209377163267  0.0526108627883675  0.0511426753737151
```

The following function represents the output characteristics of Tracer in 50 minute time interval (Y-Axis-Mbq  ; X-Axis : Time in minutes)

Now i would like to Sample the Output Curve into 19 frames

```
4 frames : Each of 15 seconds time interval
2 frames : Each of 30 seconds time interval
2 frames : Each of 60 seconds time interval
11 frames : Each of 200 seconds time interval
```

and plot each of the Respective frames in a plot, kindly suggest me some methodology to approach this problem

Comment: What is the time spacing between samples? Is it 6 seconds?

Comment: @jojek :Yes its 6 seconds